# React - Get the ref present in child component in the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm not trying to do anything hacky using refs. I just need the ref to the element because the element is a canvas, and to draw on a canvas you need its ref.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  clickDraw = () => {
    // when button clicked, get the canvas context and draw on it.
    // how?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickDraw}> Draw </button>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw something on the canvas once it's mounted
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas width={300}
              height={500}
              ref={canvasRef => this.canvas = canvasRef}>
      </canvas>
    );
  }
}
```

=====

Something I tried (which technically works but feels strange) is define the `<canvas>` in the parent, so in its ref function, `this` refers to the parent component. Then I pass the `<canvas>` and `this.canvas` to the child as two separate props. I return the `<canvas>` (named `this.props.canvasJSX`) in the child's render function, and I use `this.canvas` (named `this.props.canvasRef`) to get its context to draw on it. See below:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  clickDraw = () => {
    // now I have access to the canvas context and can draw
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,275,250);
  }

  render() {
    const canvas = (
      <canvas width={300}
              height={500}
              ref={canvasRef => this.canvas = canvasRef}>
      </canvas>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickDraw}> Draw </button>
        <Child canvasJSX={canvas}
               canvasRef={this.canvas} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const ctx = this.props.canvasRef.getContext('2d');
    // draw something on the canvas once it's mounted
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.canvas;
  }
}
```

Is there a more standard way of achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access refs of a child component in the parent component>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647061/how-do-i-access-refs-of-a-child-component-in-the-parent-component)

Comment: please use getter and setter in parent Component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should actually be using the first approach and you can access the child elements refs in the parent

```
class Parent extends Component {
  clickDraw = () => {
    // when button clicked, get the canvas context and draw on it.
    const ctx = this.childCanvas.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,275,250);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickDraw}> Draw </button>
        <Child ref={(ip) => this.childCanvas = ip}/>;
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.canvas = null;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw something on the canvas once it's mounted
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas width={300}
              height={500}
              ref={canvasRef => this.canvas = canvasRef}>
      </canvas>
    );
  }
}
```

You can only use this approach is the child component is declared as a `class`.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect except a slight typo (`refs` should be `ref`) which I made an edit for.

Comment: Shubham I'm not sure how to do this implementation for multiple HTML elements [my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pulnct?file=Posts.js)

Comment: @Omar, Edited your Snippet check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yqcgey?file=Posts.js

Answer (score 1):

If it cannot be avoided the suggested pattern extracted from the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) would be:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const Child = ({setRef}) => <input type="text" ref={setRef} />;

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Call function on Child dom element
        this.childInput.focus();
    }
    setRef(input) {
        this.childInput = input;
    }
    render() {
        return <Child setRef={this.setRef} />
    }
}
```

The **Parent** passes a function as prop bound to **Parent**'s `this`. React will call the **Child**'s `ref` callback `setRef` and attach the `childInput` property to `this` which as we already noted points to the **Parent**.