# How to get reference to child dom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement wrapper tags that binds to events on child DOM element and then does something according to them.

I have following code:

```
const Wrapper: React.FC = (props) => {
    // How do I get access to child div DOM element here??
    someComponent.eventListenerOn(childDOMElement);

    return <>{props.children}</>;
};

const ChildStuff: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div id="xyzzy"></div>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};
```

In `Wrapper`, how do I get access to child DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with React `ref`, try to check here [How do I access refs of a child component in the parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647061/how-do-i-access-refs-of-a-child-component-in-the-parent-component)

And React document about ref: [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access any DOM element. However, you'll need to wait until react writes its changes to DOM and then you can access it using `useEffect` hook. Here's how you do it using hooks:

```
const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const ref = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current) {
        // ref.current has the DOM element. Do what you want.
      }
    })

    return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
};

const ChildStuff = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div id="xyzzy"></div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: In functional component, useRef should be used instead of createRef

Comment: Nice catch. Updated it. For anyone wondering why, read more about [createRef vs useRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620698/whats-the-difference-between-useref-and-createref)